# Get closest Sunday and Saturday in current week with PHP

Tags: php

Given today's date, is there an elegant way to get the previous Sunday's and the next Saturday's date?

So, given today's date of 12/12/2013, I would want to get back 12/8/2013 for the Sunday and 12/14/2013 for the Saturday.

If given a Sunday, for example 12/15/2013, I would want to get back 12/15/2013 for the Sunday and 12/21/2013 for the Saturday.

If given a Saturday, for example 12/21/2013, I would want to get back 12/15/2013 for the Sunday and 12/21/2013 for the Saturday.

And so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

`DateTime()` accepts relative formats:

```
echo (new DateTime('last Saturday'))->format("Y-m-d");
echo (new DateTime('next Saturday'))->format("Y-m-d");
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/b4i5R1)

Comment: The first one should be `echo (new DateTime('last Sunday'))->format("Y-m-d");` to get back the Sunday instead of the Saturday. But will this work if it is currently Sunday? Or would it return the previous Sunday?

Comment: It will return the previous sunday: http://codepad.viper-7.com/oRV8r1

Comment: This is the problem I was having with strtotime in the first place -- I need it to return the current day and the next Saturday if it is currently Sunday. I couldn't figure out a way to do this without first checking to see if it was Sunday which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: That's such an easy check to do. Is there a reason why you don't want to do it?

Comment: I was looking for a more elegant way of doing it if there was one.